# How do I view or list dataflow jobs VPCs/networks?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, dataflow

I launch some dataflow jobs in different VPCs and some not in VPCs

Where do I see what VPC/subnetwork a dataflow job is running in? This should be obvious but I can't find this info in the web UI. How can I list all my dataflow jobs in project XYZ and get a table that looks something like `<job name> : <VPC/subnetwork>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can have this information in the console. Go to the job, and click on the REST button in the bottom right corner. In the popup, search for the `environment -> worker-pool` part. scroll, scroll and scroll, and you find the Network (here default)

[image]

You can find the detail of the API [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs#Job.WorkerPool)

You can't have this level of detail in one request. You have to get all the jobId before and then ask the full description of each JobId to get the network value (add the `view=JOB_VIEW_ALL` to your API URI to call)

Comment: I didn't achieve this with gcloud command. I think you have to script it with API call and curl + jq